# Separating consecutive code blocks

Tags: support, code-formatting

Currently, trying to put two code blocks one after the other results in one big code block.

```
CodeBlock1
{
   // Hey, look at me!
}

CodeBlock2
{
   // I'm different (but not really).
}
```

How do I separate these blocks without typing anything in between (as shown below)?

```
CodeBlock1
{
   // Hey, look at me!
}
```

You shall not pass!

```
CodeBlock2
{
   // I'm different (but not really).
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
    Use an HTML comment

<!-- tsk -->

    to separate them.
```

Result:

```
Use an HTML comment
```

```
to separate them.
```

Comment: That works, although I wish a simple newline would do.

Comment: Well, that's difficult, how many empty lines signal a new code block? People often have a surprisingly large number of consecutive empty lines in their code.

Comment: "how many empty lines signal a new code block?" just one if empty lines within the code also needed to be indented 4 spaces, which makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @JackDouglas you can't visually tell the difference between a line with 3 spaces and 4 spaces. Having *trailing* whitespace change the look of a document would be a disaster.

Answer (score 9):

Either use ```` ``` ```` for both blocks:

````
```
first block
```

```
second block
```
````

or for just one of the blocks

````
```
first block
```

    second block
````

Both options look like this:

```
first block
```

```
second block
```

Comment: Probably the preferred way now - code fences didn't exist when the question was asked, and this is so much more intuitive

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Markdown doesn't care how many lines you add in between. If there's nothing there, it's still the same code block. That's how Markdown works. If you don't want physical text between them, you can use something that Markdown will remove to make it break the code block *thinking* there's something there. Most commonly an empty HMTL comment: `<!-- -->`

```
CodeBlock1
{
   // Hey, look at me!
}
```

```
CodeBlock2
{
   // I'm different (but not really).
}
```

Since you're using an HTML comment, also consider if your code will be highlighted, and properly. If not, considering using that [comment to specify the language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) so it *does* get highlighted properly. It will make the post look nicer while achieving your goal at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML carriage return entity `&#13;` or an invisible character like the [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) `&shy;`. While not ideal, it works

```
    code block 1
&#13;

    code block 2
```

Results in:

```
code block 1
```

```
code block 2
```

Note that Stack Exchange's interpreter requires an additional line break after the entity (unlike some other Markdown interpreters).