# Is syntax highlighting only applied to code after posting?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, markdown-preview

Is syntax highlighting only applied to code after the post is posted?

```
// test code 
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
   s = s + "abc" + 'd'
}
```

Also, will the formatted blocks that were shown as being separate after each time I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> be merged?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I have no clue what you are getting at. Or were you just testing the system?

Comment: Guessing at question #1: There's a five second delay after any activity in the textfield before syntax highlighting is applied.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly, but these links might cover it:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: The editing preview gets highlighted as well, but only after a delay.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time for highlights to appear while creating your posts. Leave the text box out of focus, make yourself some coffee and when you come back, you'll notice that language highlighter is working for you.

```c
// test code 
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
   s = s + "abc" + 'd'
}
```

And here's the screenshot:

[image: screencap]

<sub>of course, I notice now that it isn't C-language :/</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The preview of your post, while editing, does get syntax highlighting applied. However, it is only applied if you *stop* editing and wait for 5 seconds.

The delay is applied to prevent highlighting from having to be re-calculated on every keypress.