# Code sample not syntax highlighted in edit mode, but is highlighted after posting

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

When viewing my post in edit mode, the code blocks do not have syntax highlighting, even after [waiting for a while first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180620).  After submitting it, [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22176358) does have syntax highlighting.

I can also get the syntax highlighting to update in edit mode if I explicitly add the `<!-- language: lang-c# -->` before the code block, but without it will never update with highlighting.

Is this considered as a bug? Sometimes I take some time to find why the code is not being syntax highlighting and I find it difficult to reviewing my code blocks in edit mode without it.

**Update:** Syntax highlighting seems to work in the preview when I *modify* an already-posted post in just about any way {[1(C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22176358), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22045444)}, but for new posts it just refuses to work unless given a language hint.

Comment: There is a delay, this is not a bug.

Comment: No,this is not a delay because I take more than half hour for writing the post and it **never** has syntax highlighting in that period in edit mode,or you can try to go inside edit mode of that post and see whether it will show you the syntax highlighting,thanks

Comment: Ah, indeed, this is a regression. It *should* work the way I described, but it is currently b0rken.

Comment: Ya, it might be caused by having very long line in the code sample.

Comment: No, I confirmed the problem with other posts.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229511/115866

Comment: Waiting for next build:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this problem.

What seems to be happening is that (in the absence of explicit `<!-- language: foo -->` hints) the syntax highlighting is based on the tags: to know that your code is C# and should be highlighted as such, the question needs to be tagged with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) (or some other tag associated with that language).

However, until you've actually posted the question, it doesn't really *have* any fixed tags.  Yes, there's a box at the bottom of the edit form where you can select some tags to apply to the question when you post it, but the syntax highlighter doesn't seem to pay any attention it — it only cares about the tags the question already had *before* you started editing it.

Arguably, the syntax highlighting rules *should* change whenever the tag list is changed in the tag editor box.  If so, this is a bug / missing feature.

Comment: It used to work just fine; but Balpha fixed it again.