# Syntax highlighting doesn't work in the preview when asking a new question

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, editor

Actual Post:

[image: Actual Post]

Preview while writing the question:

[image: Preview]

Comment: I've found you need to click off the text area before it colors the code preview. Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried it doesn't seem to help though preview never gets colored.

Answer (score 1):

On sites that don't have a default syntax highlighter (like e.g. tex.se), the syntax highlighting only runs once a question has tags. Rather, it's supposed to – the "rerun highlighting on tag change" was broken. Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Is [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224113/code-sample-not-syntax-highlighted-in-edit-mode-but-is-highlighted-after-postin) related / the same?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, thanks.

Comment: And there was much rejoicing!