# Broken link in Help Center pointing to Google Prettify

Tags: bug

I want to report a [broken link to Google Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) on the help center page about [formatting](https://serverfault.com/help/formatting).

As mentioned on [google code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-code-prettify/), the project moved to [github](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

Some other links in the linked meta question ([will be inferred from the question's tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)) are broken as well.

Comment: Seems to have the same problem network-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest changing the link to point to the [README.md](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md) on github:

```
https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md
```