# Can someone fix the broken links in this historically-locked question?

Tags: support, meta, locked-questions, broken-link

This contains some broken links:

*[Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)*

But it can not changed, because it is locked.

Can someone fix this?

Comment: I think only mods can edit locked posts. You can flag for mod attention if that's the case then

Comment: There is no option to flag it.

Comment: Oh yeah. Or You have meta. Mention the edits you want there

Comment: For reference, [these](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) [are](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src) the broken links. The second one isn't exactly broken, but it provides nothing useful to the post anymore.

Comment: The FAQ [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) mentions what to do in order to fix serious problems with historically-locked posts (the one you linked is one).

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of FAQ. The answer in FAQ suggests to post a new question in meta in case of any serious problem like broken link etc. And this is exactly what the op has done.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot fix it yourself, however, a moderator can. Flag the post for moderator attention and explain the situation ("link in text xxx is broken, could you replace it with yyy or remove it?").

Now, if it's historically locked, as this question is, you *almost* did the proper thing. Ask on the Meta of the *corresponding site* to bring attention to the question.

<sub>Note that this question was originally posted on Meta Stack Overflow. This question is currently on the correct site, as it was migrated.</sub>

Comment: You cannot flag locked posts for mods. You can, however, flag another post and provide a link to the relevant one.

Comment: @Stormblessed Read the whole answer before commenting, please. Also see the latest edit for a slight clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I've taken the liberty of fixing the links - there was a request to delete it but I figure there's a little life left in the question, and I kind of did a bit of a workflow to try to fix these.

1. Custom flag the (this?) question explaining the situation and the value in fixing it. If nothing else, it makes sure a mod sees it. Link the historically locked question too, and any information that's helpful to provide context.
2. Flags suck a bit in terms of nuance - if you can give corrected links to be fixed, it's awesome. As we're wont, I ended up creating a [gist](https://gist.github.com/JourneymanGeek/136caf29a26a56c82b113bd4dd1387a6) with the intention of workshopping it and fixed it on my own (I got distracted). This is in no way mandatory, but if I was telling someone else to fix it, it probably saves a lot of effort, and ensures we're on the same page. As suggested in the comments, I guess.

Comment: You can't custom flag historically-locked questions. Per the FAQ and CM guidance, the "correct" way to have historically locked questions edited is through a meta post like this one.

Comment: Which is kinda what I'd said.  The main point being we can't keep track of everything and it's nice to have stuff brought to our attention

Comment: We need to redefine what an *helpful* flag means. ...